# Create Min and Max columns for each date column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

### DataFrame

| ID | DateMade | DelDate | ExpDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 05/06/2020 | 06/05/2022 |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 07/06/2020 | 07/05/2022 |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 07/06/2020 | 09/09/2022 |
| 2 | 03/04/2020 | 07/08/2020 | 15/12/2022 |
| 2 | 05/06/2020 | 23/08/2020 | 31/12/2022 |
| 2 | 01/01/2021 | 31/08/2020 | 09/01/2023 |

What I want to do is groupby ID and create columns for the Min and Max date for each column. But I'm not sure where to start. I know there's aggregate functions out there that work well with one column but I'm wondering is there a straight forward solution when dealing with multiple columns?

### Desired Output

| ID | DateMade_Min | DateMade_Max | DelDate_Min | DelDate_Max | ExpDate_Min | ExpDate_Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 01/01/2020 | 05/06/2020 | 07/06/2020 | 06/05/2022 | 09/09/2022 |
| 2 | 03/04/2020 | 01/01/2021 | 07/08/2020 | 31/08/2020 | 15/12/2022 | 09/01/2023 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert columns by list to datetimes in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then correct aggregation `min` and `max`, flatten `MultiIndex` with `capitalize`:

```
cols = ['DateMade','DelDate','ExpDate']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

df1 = df.groupby('ID')[cols].agg(['min','max'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1].capitalize()}')
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   ID DateMade_Min DateMade_Max DelDate_Min DelDate_Max ExpDate_Min  \
0   1   2020-01-01   2020-01-01  2020-06-05  2020-06-07  2022-05-06   
1   2   2020-04-03   2021-01-01  2020-08-07  2020-08-31  2022-12-15   

  ExpDate_Max  
0  2022-09-09  
1  2023-01-09
```

For orginal format of datetimes add lambda function with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
cols = ['DateMade','DelDate','ExpDate']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

df1 = df.groupby('ID')[cols].agg(['min','max'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1].capitalize()}')

df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))

df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   ID DateMade_Min DateMade_Max DelDate_Min DelDate_Max ExpDate_Min  \
0   1   01/01/2020   01/01/2020  05/06/2020  07/06/2020  06/05/2022   
1   2   03/04/2020   01/01/2021  07/08/2020  31/08/2020  15/12/2022   

  ExpDate_Max  
0  09/09/2022  
1  09/01/2023
```